# MATLAB: How do I display numerical values based on time that synchronize with a video and it's time?

Tags: matlab, video

I am trying to construct a program that displays a video of experiments along with voltage and current readings that correspond with the time in the video. I first thing that I need to know is how to make a numerical display that changes based on time and then how to sync it with the video time. If this is not possible in Matlab, please let me know of any other options. Thank you.

Comment: The `processing` tag is about the language Processing, are you trying to do something with that language?

Comment: No, my apologies, thank you for the clarification! I am trying to work in Matlab.